# Insert data in mysql table

Tags: php, mysql

I have problem with inserting data in mysql by PHP code

I use a WAMP server for executing my codes and my database collection is utf8_persian_ci

When I run the code in PHP, using the code below, it doesn't work.

**PHP Code:**

```
$query="insert into lesson_form(lessid,teachid,tvahed,maghta,snazari,samali,skargahi,zamantashkil,ahdaf,masli,mfarei,mosharekat,tamrinat,project,bfaaliat,bmidterm,bfinal)
        values ($lessid,$teacherid,$tvahed,$maghta,$snazari,$samali,$skargahi,$zaman,$ahdaf,$masli,$mfarei,$mosharekat,$tamrinat,$project,$bfaaliat,$bmidterm,$bfinal);";

mysqli_query($con,"set names 'utf8'");        

$run_query=mysqli_query($con,$query);
if (mysqli_query($con, $query))
{
    echo "New record created successfully";
} 
else 
{
    echo "Error: " . "<br>" . mysqli_error($con);
}
```

But when I execute the MySQL statement in PhpMyAdmin page it works:

**MySQL Statement**

```
INSERT INTO lesson_form(lessid,teachid,tvahed,maghta, snazari,samali,skargahi,zamantashkil,ahdaf,masli,mfarei, mosharekat,tamrinat,project,bfaaliat,bmidterm,bfinal) values (101,27401,3,'کارش',48,48, 48,'شنبه','حضو','www.w3school.com','جز','tamrinat', '','',12,4,4)
```

Comment: Is there  is any error log is printing @Zavosh

Comment: So, what does _"doesn't work"_ mean? Error messages on screen/in your log file? Blank screen? Nothing inserted in the DB? Wrong data inserted? Computer crashes? Server caught on fire?

Comment: You are open to [SQL Injections](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) and should really use [Prepared Statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) instead of concatenating your queries. Even if you do escape your inputs (which we don't know if you do or not), you're still not as safe as you would think.

Comment: Directly inserting variable into SQL query is so... _some ancient year number_ . Use `mysqli` or `PDO` and use variable binding instead.

Answer (score 0):

> You **have not added single quotes into sql query** so please add those replace your $query parameter with i have given below n try

```
$query = "insert into lesson_form(lessid,teachid,tvahed,maghta,
    snazari,samali,skargahi,zamantashkil,ahdaf,masli,mfarei,
    mosharekat,tamrinat,project,bfaaliat,bmidterm,bfinal)
    values ('".$lessid."','".$teacherid."','".$tvahed."','".$maghta."','".$snazari."','".$samali."','".$skargahi."'
    ,'".$zaman."','".$ahdaf."','".$masli."','".$mfarei."','".$mosharekat."','".$tamrinat."'
    ,'".$project."','".$bfaaliat."','".$bmidterm."','".$bfinal."');";
```

Hope this will help :)

Comment: @zavosh please mark question right and close the questing thank you :)